# Centrar Inputs en Boostrap 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

Me requiero centrar los `inputs` de **nombre contacto teléfono** el siguiente formulario en `boostrap 4` , en `boostrap 3` si me funcionaba 
[image: aplicacion]

```html
  <div class=" form-horizontal bg-light ">


        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })



        <div class="form-group ">
            <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
            <div class="col-md-8 ">
                @Html.DropDownList("PosicionId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @placeholder = "Posicion ", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PosicionId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Nombre del Candidato ", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Necesito que quede así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Lo que requieres es centrar los input con respecto al ancho total? ¿O pegar un input del otro para que sean consecutivos?

Comment: Requiero que el input quede del lado derecho y el icono lado izq con el ancho total del contenedor para abajo como la imagen de arriba

Comment: Gracias por subir la segunda imagen.

Comment: algo asi era el ejemplo que intento hacer , al actualizar de bootrap se perdio el contenido

Comment: @MarceloMP al actualizar la versión Bootstrap  es claro que van a cambiar varias cosas, te aconsejo para un futuro [revisar la doc sobre migración](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/) para que no tengas problemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo lo haria de la siguiente manera:

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
  
  <div class="container py-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1 text-right">
        <span>
          <i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-11">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1 text-right">
        <span>
          <i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-11">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><div class="row">
      <div class="col-1 text-right">
        <span>
          <i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-11">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Asi te quedan los iconos a la izquierda y los inputs a la derecha.

Answer (score 2):

Esto es un ejemplo que puedes encontrar en la pagina oficial de [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/)

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="colFormLabelSm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="colFormLabelSm" placeholder="col-form-label-sm">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Por lo tanto, según lo que veo en tu código deberías agregarle al `div` la clase `row`

```
<div class="form-group row ">
            <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><i class="fa fa-user bigicon"></i></span>
            <div class="col-md-8 ">
                @Html.DropDownList("PosicionId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @placeholder = "Posicion ", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PosicionId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>
```

Y de igual manera puedes revisar el material que te aporta bootstrap en su pagina es de mucha ayuda, espero que te sirva, saludos

Comment: con ese codigo se alinea el icono con el input ,en ese caso como centro el contenido

Comment: @MarceloMP Intenta agregarle a ese mismo `div` la clase `justify-content-center` a ver que tal

Comment: Siguen igual no se centran , probe con esa clase y form horizontal y tampoco

Comment: Pues es complicado cuando colocas varias clases ya que unas bloquean algunos elementos que aportan otros, añadele `d-flex`

Comment: Sino, ponle `style='margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto'`

Comment: No me funciono , intente con todas . D-flex lo comprime

Comment: Le hiciste el `style`?  probablemente esto es lo que no te deja `<div class=" form-horizontal bg-light ">` por el form horizontal

Comment: Esta respuesta es correcta, la clase `.form-horizontal` existe en BS3 pero no en BS4. En la versión 3 haría lo mismo que hace la clase `.row`, es por esto que debes añadirla a todos los div con clase `.form-group`. Para centrar debes usar `.mx-auto` para elementos con `display: block` o `.text-center` para elementos de tipo texto.